# Is there a canonical way to present a "loading" pop-up for a slow loading web page?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom-events

**Preface:**

I have a web app that works in a simple way:

1. User clicks a button on page 1. This submits a POST request for page 2.
2. Page 2 takes 1-2 minutes to retrieve data on the back-end.
3. Page 2 back end sends the computed HTML to the browser, where it takes a while (10-30 seconds) to render.

The **obvious** usability problem here is that the user, when clicking the button in step #1, has to sit there while the web page seemingly does nothing (the browser shows that it's connecting to page #2 on the status bar, but most users don't notice that); and THEN it replaces the content of page #1 with an EMPTY page which also sits there seemingly doing nothing, while the content is being rendered and DOM is built from a large data set.

I am leaving aside the fact that the above solution is awfully engineered, and needs to be redesigned properly to: (1) Make use of AJAX to retrieve the data; and/or (2) Retrieve the data in smaller (human-consumable) chunks and load more data as needed incrementally. Absent such a re-engineering due to resource constraints, **I'm trying to apply a quick and dirty usability fix** of the following nature:

A. Upon clicking the button on page #1, the user is presented with a modal pop-up that says "Processing and reloading data. This may take ~3 minutes to complete".

B. Importantly, the modal pop-up should persist (ore at least be seemlessly re-created) upon Page 2 load start.

---

**Question**:

**What is the "best practice" approach to building such a modal pop-up?**

Obviously, #A alone is trivial to achieve (pop-up on Page 1 which will stay till the HTTP response from Page 2 arrives on the client and Page 2 starts to render replacing page 1).

But what is the best way to preserve/re-clone this pop-up when Page 2 arrives? The 2 problems here are to achieve - as much as possible - seamless transition from pop-up before and pop-up after the HTTP response; and more importantly, avoid having to wait for the full Page #2 to render (for 30 seconds before displaying the pop-up).

**Clarification:**

- Any suggested approach should NOT be AJAX. E.g. anything being done must be contained in the same HTML content that Page 2's HTTP response sent.
- I'm looking for general technical pointers, not necessarily example code. Something on the order of "Use `window.onload` handler to do this" (obviously the wrong answer correctness wise).
- The solution should ideally be using pure Javascript, though if a **better** solution using jQuery or YUI exists, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

So this is actually a pretty simple fix. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAPuj/2) for some sample overlay code.

When your page is ready, simply make this call (if you're using jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Basically, by default, your overlay will be there and anything loading underneath will be hidden. Once everything is loaded, just fade out your overlay and you're done! You don't need any special scripts or anything, just have your overlay turned on by default and turn it off when you're ready.

If you want to start using this for AJAX, before you make your ajax call, just call `$('.overlay').fadeIn();` It's also really easy to change the text inside the overlay. Just find the node,

```
$('.overlay').find('.message p').text('Some new text').end().fadeIn();
```

If you just want to use standard JS, you can attach the function to `window.onload` as you suggested, but that only detects when the page is ready, not the DOM, as jQuery's `.ready()` does.

Comment: would be wise to add the overlay with js (or to use e.g. modernizr and add a style for `html.no-js .overlay {display:none}`. otherwise, no js or a js error means you'd get an overlay that you can't get rid of.

Comment: yep, that's a good idea. but truth be told, very very very very few people aren't using js these days. it's a fraction of a percent.

Comment: a lot more than a fraction of a percent of websites have js errors :), or logic errors e.g. adding the overlay removal to an ajax success handler and having no error handler

Comment: THAT is true for sure ;) but if you're writing proper error handling code, you should be able to take care of that, right?

Comment: As a canonical generalization: Big if :D

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand from your thesis question (it's a bunch to read honestly)

- I assume your page request is just the normal "click this link and load awfully slow page".
- You want to indicate it's loading something awfully slow
- Show the indicator at page 2 arrival for another 10+ seconds to render

Well, you should load page 2's the modal as early as possible. Load the libraries and the script on the head. Since parsing is usually top-down, the modal should before the slow content so that it's parsed and made available for scripts.

Take advantage of jQuery's `$(document).ready()` which executes as soon as the DOM is ready instead of `window.onload`, which executes when all contents are rendered (DOM, images and all)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> <!--libraries like jquery-->
<script>
    $(function(){             //execute dialog as soon as 
        $('#modal').dialog(); //the modal div is available
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div id="modal"></div>
    <!--the rest of the slow rendering page-->
</div>
```